# hyperledger blockchain-explorer scripts error

Tags: hyperledger-explorer

The explorer display an empty page, so I debugged the scripts.

On this step, it display well with data. But the channels property is undefined, and explorer page will display empty later. Can anyone help? Thanks!

[>Screenshot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwVOr.jpg)

Comment: can you attach the log files please?

Answer (score 0):

In your config, make sure you have at least one peer with the following 4 properties:  "requests", "events", "server-hostname", "tls_cacerts". Otherwise, the call to `/api/channels` times out.